# What's the difference between ‘A increased with B’ and ’A increased with increasing B?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between ‘A increased with B’ and ’A increased with increasing B?
Do they have the same meaning? Or does ‘A increased with B’ also have the meaning of ‘A increased with decreasing B’?
And how about ‘A increased with increased B’? Confused.

Comment: How could "A increased with B" mean that B is decreasing? Do you have any real world context for these phrases? (E.g., weather reports: "Rain increased with increasing wind.")

Comment: Thank you. "Rain increased with increasing wind' and "Rain increased with wind". Does these two sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: You can go **with** someone when that someone is going in the first place, and going in the same direction. HTH.

Comment: Are you reading a piece of work that contains this or are you trying to write a piece which expresses one of the concepts? If I were trying to say that A increased at the same time as B increased (with the implication that the increase of in A was caused by the increase in B or that both increases had a common cause) I would probably say "A increased as B increased".

Comment: Thank you. BoldBen. Yes, I am writing a piece and it is not easy since I am not a native speak. Need a lot of helps. Does this sentence ‘The samples exhibited increased nitrogen content compared with the control’ look ok to you.

Comment: ‘A increased with B’ means that A got pregnant when B showed up.

Comment: ***Do** these two sentences have the same meaning?* Probably not.There is still not enough context to say for certain what you mean. **1** "Rain increased with increasing wind' -- I think you mean: *As the wind increased, so did the rain* **2** *"Rain increased with wind"* -- *"As the rain increased, the wind started to blow."*

Answer (score 1):

It seems common to assume that ‘A increasing with B’ means that B is also increasing. It sounds like the default case. Adding additional terms 'with *increasing* B' sounds redundant and as such unnecessary.

It makes sense if you consider a different word. ‘A increased as B rotated’ would tell you that the relationship needs explaining.

‘A increased with increased B’ should be stated as ‘A increased as B increased’. If it is good enough for A then it should be for B.

Comment: Thank you so much. ‘The samples exhibited increased nitrogen content compared with the control.’ Is this sentence correct? More nitrogen in the sample.

Comment: The significant word here is **with**. See my comment at OP.

Answer (score 0):

It is a long-established and widespread mathematical or scientific convention to say of two variables that, if an increase in one is associated with an increase in the other, one increases with the other. "A increases with B".

As a perfect example: "For all positive integers X, X squared increases with X."

As a more understandable but less than perfect (because some people may be very tall and also unusually thin and light) example: "Weight increases with height".

It also makes sense to say "A increases as B increases". This is clear and unambiguous and does not rely on knowing the mathematical convention.

If "A increases with decreasing B" it simply means the opposite of the above. For example: "Poverty increases with decreasing income".

"A increased with increased B" simply describes what happened in the past. For example "In our last field trials, growth increased with increased nitrogen application."

Answer (score -4):

Both are different because if we change the term I.e

"A is directly proportional to B" which means A increases when B increases, simultaneously.

if we look at the second one "A increased with B", normally a person would interpret it as the first one only. but if we look at it carefully it is an incomplete information given to us.

it can either mean "A increased with decreasing B" or "A increased with increasing B" and the last one would be "A increased with constant B"

hope it helps